# Magento: How to create an account with email and password only

Tags: magento, registration, magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7.

I would like to simplify the create account (register new user) to show and require only the email and a password.

The user would only fill in the other info (like name, address, etc) when making a purchase.

The idea behind is that every user would need to give out the email address in order to view the site content.

I'm already using [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wabism-members-only-7590.html) in order to make the the site available only to login users. I need a way to simplify the register process to include only email and password

Answer (score 1):

`app/design/frontend/default/{yourtheme}/template/customer/form/register.phtml`

and comment out the fields that you don't want.

This is what you want, right?

Comment: I need to check, but it seems to be that. I just have one doubt. how can I force the user to include other info like TAXVAT before checkout?

Comment: Just enable `Show VAT Number on Frontend` in `System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Create New account options` and your customer will see `VAT Number` field while filling address in Checkout process

Comment: I actually needed to comment out the lines of the file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml, but that's what I needed. let me just check the other part about VAT.

Comment: Yeah sure, let me know if you stuck anywhere.

Comment: Just commenting out the lines does not allow us to create a new account. when I click on Register, I get notices saying the name and other fields are required. any idea?

Comment: Ohh. I think the required field for `Firstname` and `Lastname` is set to `Yes` in `eav_attribute` database table. If you set it to `No`, you should be good to go I guess.

Comment: I'd rather not touch the db right now. I'll leave this as it is now, with all fields. I'll improve this later if really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this extension from Magento Connect - [Fast Registration](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/19173/s/fast-registration-6987/) it allow customer registration only with Email & Password